# Rename Android Studio module through gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

When importing two projects with two sub modules with the same name, they show up as following in Android Studio:

```
project1/library[library]

project2/library[project2-library]
```

I then renamed them to:

```
project1/library[project1]

project2/library[project2]
```

Is there a way to do this through gradle programatically during the first import via build.gradle?

(Since we don't save our *.iml files in git this is wrong when other developers import our projects. One could rename the directory library, in order two have two different names and then save in git. Since these are third party libraries Id like to keep them as is.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no easy way to do what you want -- in `build.gradle` files you don't have direct control over what modules will be named when they're imported.

If you're thinking about checking in the .iml files, I'd discourage that -- they get regenerated every time you re-sync the project, and changes made there quickly get lost.

You could use symlinks, either checking them into source control (they're generally preserved by source control systems), or maybe generating them with a one-time script new developers could use when setting up their environments. If you really want to generate the symlinks programmatically through the build file, you can try it, but it's likely to take a lot of effort and it may not work out. If you want to go down that road, some pointers:

- You'd probably have to do it in the top-level `build.gradle` file (the one that's normally empty); by the time it gets to a module's `build.gradle`, it's too late. Even then, I'm not sure how things get evaluated, and if it's too late to set up symlinks at the time the top-level build file is executed.
- Bear in mind that this file is run not only on import but on every build as well, so anything you need to do needs to bail out harmlessly and quickly if it's not needed. I'm not sure if there's a way to tell if the build file is being executed in the context of a build, an import, or something else.